# What kind of phrase is "Bob reliable"

Tags: syntax

Consider the sentence:

a. Betty considers Bob reliable.

b. Betty considers Bob to be reliable.

It is believed that "Bob reliable" is a small clause and it is an AGRP.  However for sentence b, "Bob to be reliable" is usually regarded to be a TP.

What do Minimalist Program or any other theories think about the unit "Bob reliable"?
And I am also confused with the difference between small clause and clause.

I really appreciate it if you help me figure it out. Thanks very much!

Comment: _Bob reliable_ is the remains of the infinitive clause _(for) Bob (to be) reliable_, which is the object of _consider_. _[To be_-deletion](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/tobeandnottobe.pdf) has applied, as it often does with _consider_; and as usual the subject infinitive complementizer _for_ is deleted. As for what the MP might think of it, I leave that to those who believe in it.

Comment: It is not a phrase. It is a mis-parse.

Comment: @Lambie, a. is grammatical in my dialect of English.

Comment: @jlawler huh, it never even occurred to me that it would be the remains of an infinitive clause. I'd always thought of it as a direct object and adjectival predicate of the verb consider, like a sort of transitive copula

Comment: @AndreasZUERCHER Yes, of course. But not just "Bob reliable".

Comment: @Tristan Then of course it is, for you. Everybody builds their own grammar, based on how **they** understand things; there isn't any secret codebook, after all. And that's how syntax changes, one step at a time.

Comment: @jlawler what you have mentioned is very insightful, then I carry on with this following question. When we use predicates like "believe", it is felicitious to say "John believes smart" but rather "John believes to be smart" Why is that then?

Comment: @Lambie could you please explain more about mis-parse? I am not really clear with this term.

Comment: @Xia.Yili Take a look at [the original paper on _To be_-Deletion_](https://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/tobeandnottobe.pdf) to get some idea how it works. It's governed by the predicate, but not just any predicate in any context. The rule is intricately associated with the meaning of the predicate.

Comment: Oh, and as for *_John believes (to be) smart_, the predicate _believe_ doesn't take that type of complement clause, so it's ungrammatical (hence the *). This is the A configuration, which does not have a noun between the predicate and the complement verb; the B configuration does have a noun there: _John believes Mary (to be) competent_. Most of the predicates that show up with _To be_-Deletion are [Equi or Raising verbs](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Comment: To parse is to break an utterance down into its constituent parts. This: "What kind of phrase is "Bob reliable" is  not a phrase. It has to be read as: Betty considers Bob to be reliable. As jlawler explains.

Comment: @Lambie I understand now. Thanks so much for clarification.  Thanks so much Jilawler for recommending the paper about to be-delection. I will take a deep look in to it.